# JavaScript passing ";" as the first parameter in a "for" statement

Tags: javascript

I have been studding the jQuery source code and I noticed this when examining the `jQuery.fn.extend` function:

```
for ( ; i < length; i++ ){
    code
}
```

Why is there a `;` at the beginning? Similarly, I have noticed a few javascript libraries beginning like so:

```
; (function (){ ...
```

Without any prior code.

Why is this? How is this syntactically correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: may be in first case i is initialized before.So initialization is not necessary and that's why it is kept empty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript `for` loop has three **optional** parameters. So, you can omit all of its three parameters.

In your code,

```
for( ; i < length; i++)
```

the first parameter is omitted. `;` is not passed as parameter. `;` is just a delimiter. The syntax of the `for` loop is

---

```
for( [optional parameter 1] ; [optional parameter 2] ; [optional parameter 3] )
```

***OR***

```
for ([initialization] ; [condition] ; [final-expression])
```

---

So the following statements are syntactically correct

```
for( ; i < length; i ++ )  // first parameter is omitted
for( ; i < length; ) // first and third parameters are omitted
for( ; ; ) // all parameters are omitted
```

Answer (score 5):

Those two snippets are unrelated.

The first one is an empty statement. A `for` loop takes 3 statements; if you initialize the variable before the loop you don't need to initialize it inside, but the statement **has** to be there, hence the empty statement:

```
var i=0;
for (; i<10; i++) {}
```

A typical example is `for(;;)`, same as `while(true)` but shorter.

The second piece of code is the beginning of an IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression). The semicolon at the start is to avoid concatenation errors from other JavaScript files that may be missing a semicolon, otherwise the IIFE might be interpreted as a function call, for example:

```
// file1.js
var f = function(){} // oops
// file2.js
(function(){})();
```

If the file **did** include the last semicolon, then you end up with an empty statement, which is OK.

Comment: Is there actually a danger of that second part happening? Aren't `.js` files (and `<script>` blocks) parsed separately from each other?

Comment: Yes, it is a **real** danger, and has happened, and will happen, and it's a hell of a bug to track down. If you're in a serious production environment, all JavaScript is minified, and concatenated, and shipped in one single script file. I think UglifyJS has some feature or something to avoid this, not sure...

Comment: With JSHint in development and some other tools you lower the chance of this happening if you experienced before.

Answer (score 2):

The two examples are unrelated.

In the first case, a `for` statement always has three components; an initialize, a condition, and an increment statement. All three are optional, so the code `for( ; i < length; i++)` simply chooses not to initialize anything before looping.

The empty statement, `;`, is perfectly valid, there is nothing syntactically wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate topics, but to address them in-order:

In a `for` loop, you have three sections: the initialization, condition and increment/decrement sections.

The first section, the initialization, can be written directly in the `for` loop itself, such as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

Or, can precede it:

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < length; i++) {
```

Both come out to the same meaning, they just look a little different.

Regarding the last bit of code, `; (function(){ ...`, the leading `;` is just an empty statement. A semicolon in JavaScript is simply to denote an end-of-a-statement and by itself, it is valid.